# Was the Tetrarchy known under a different name by contemporaries?

Tags: ancient-history, late-antiquity

It made me curious that the [Tetrarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrarchy) should be known by a Greek name, so I've spent some time searching for a Latin alternative, but I didn't find any mention of it, including in the Latin-language version of the Wikipedia page for the Tetrarchy.

I am wondering if there was an alternative name for the rule of four emperors that was used interchangeably by Latin speakers?

Comment: Please tell us why the [Wikipedia atricle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrarchy#Terminology) doesn't answer your question  -- Applying the term "tetrarchy" to the system Diocletian set up ony started in the late 19th century.

Comment: @T.E.D.  Constantinople wasn't founded or the main imperial capital until 330,  after Constantine I abolished the Tetrarchy  and over 40 years after the Tetrarchy started.

Comment: @MAGolding [It was founded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantium#History); it just wasn't as big or important because it wasn't the capital yet.